# Customize UITableViewCell some IBOutlet elements are nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I just create a subclass of UITableViewCell. And drag some UI elements into the nib file. Then connect them into the class.
All works well on the simulator iPhone 6s, but when I run it on a device iPhone 6s some elements are nil.

For example, I have two UILabels, `daysLabel` isn't nil, but `daysStringLabel` is nil. What's the possible reason could be?

The app then crashes on here like:

```
daysLabel.isEnabled = isEnable
daysStringLabel.isEnabled = isEnable // crash
```

[image]

They are all connected:
[image]

Comment: Could you please show more code? Maybe of the full implementation? Regards.

Comment: How do you register your custom class /  create instances of the cell?

Comment: Have you tried recreating UI in interface builder?

Comment: Sorry, just got the reason, the xib was localized in other languages the connections are missing for these nil elements.

Answer (score 0):

I got the reason.

I localized the xib file, but the connections are missing in some languages xib file.